# SharePoint 2016 Publishing features and SP Designer support for them

Tags: publish, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-2016

A lot of my customers are asking about SP16 Publishing Feature information and to what extent if any SPD 2013 will support managing them.  I haven't found mcuh info at all on this topic, can someone point me to some good info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please view the keynote from Wednesday below.  SP Designer won't be needed be in 2016.  The CMS is so simple for users with the new Publishing Feature, and also new Pages (wiki pages) without the Publishing feature.  They borrowed the editor from Delve, vertical parts adding.  Unless users are making serious custom client-side code or XSLT in SPD, they shouldn't need it.  InfoPath is replaced with PowerApps.  Workflows are replaced with MS Flow.  See www.powerapps.com if you have an o365 account.  You don't need BCS cause everything is a web service now.

[The Future of SharePoint Keynote](https://vts.inxpo.com/scripts/Server.nxp?LASCmd=L:0&AI=1&ShowKey=30784&LoginType=0&InitialDisplay=1&ClientBrowser=0&DisplayItem=NULL&LangLocaleID=0&SSO=1)